# how to create a stream from images and then sharing it via a network in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, video-streaming, html5-video

I am working on an application that continuously takes still images and then streams those images as an MPEG video stream to an HTML client via some network.
I have been watching the 2014 WWDC video ["Direct Access to Video Encoding and Decoding"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/)(start: 28:50 to: 35:40). Unfortunately the video is very high level and only shows a tiny bit of code.

Based on the bits and pieces I wrote a small test program(outline shown below).

What would be the next step(s) to distribute `CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer` via the network to a HTML client?

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <VideoToolbox/VideoToolbox.h>

void compressionCallback(
        void *outputCallbackRefCon,
        void *sourceFrameRefCon,
        OSStatus status,
        VTEncodeInfoFlags infoFlags,
        CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer ){

    NSLog(@"received compressed image");
    // how to share the CMSampleBufferRef via the network to an HTML client?
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    // create VTCompressionSession stream
    VTCompressionSessionRef cpsession;
    VTCompressionSessionCreate(NULL, (CGFloat)width, (CGFloat)height, kCMVideoCodecType_H264, NULL, NULL, NULL, (void*)compressionCallback, NULL, &cpsession);

    while (true) {
        // take new image, stuff it into the session

        NSImage *NSWindowImage = /*taking the image*/
        // create a CVPixelbuffer from the image
        CVPixelBufferRef pixelbuffer = pixelBufferFromNSImage(NSWindowImage);

         // feed pixel into stream
        CMTime presentationTimeStamp = CMTimeMake(0, 1); // needs to be updated for every frame
        VTCompressionSessionEncodeFrame(cpsession, pixelbuffer, presentationTimeStamp, kCMTimeInvalid, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        VTCompressionSessionEndPass(cpsession, NO, NULL); 
    }

    return 0; // application never reaches this return statement
}
```

Comment: See https://github.com/jamesghurley/VideoCore/blob/master/transforms/Apple/H264Encode.cpp for a working implementation